# Advertising Links Websites

Tags: javascript, web-services, ftp, web-hosting

I have recently noticed that when i visit certain websites, there are usually links tied to certain words. I can't find an answer from where i have looked, and i have noticed similar trends from several websites, but especially my own.

Is this a programming, hack issue that can be solved by adding specific code or is it my hosting company doing this, or does it mean that someone has gained control to my ftp portal?

Please see the image below of what i mean and any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're called in-text contextual advertisements, though they probably have many names. Here's a wiki article about them:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-text_advertising

I don't know if Google offer these (due to how annoying they are), but I'm pretty sure AdBrite does:
http://www.adbrite.com/mb/exchange_publishers_ad_formats.php

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense but is there anything i could do about it a programming sense or any other way to eliminate them?

Comment: You could disable Javascript. There are probably some ad-blockers that will pick them up too.

Comment: Is is issue happening from my local machine? Any ideas on what is triggering this?

Comment: The webpage is responsible for hosting these atrocities code-wise, but the 'pop-up' ability is done client-side. Most likely, they are using Javascript to allow the pop-up ability, so disabling Javascript on your machine can prevent them from working.

Comment: Thanks alot man, i went ahead and disabled some ad-on extensions and this seems alright now. I have a feeling that the JQuery API extension i had wasn't a problem. But Yontoo Runtime and TheBflix browser extension are my top 2 suspects. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You probably have adware installed on your computer. Some web searches point to browser addons called "Facetheme" and "Better Links".

Comment: This is not adware. Those are in-text advertisements.

Comment: There's nothing on his site (I looked - it's easy to find given the text in the screenshot) which is supposed to be triggering them. There must be something on his computer which is injecting the ad script.

Comment: Yes, i have a feeling it might be on my local machine. Any ideas on what could trigger this?